# opening an fstream through another function

Tags: c++11, fstream

I am creating a program that decalares an fstream in `main()`  but opens it in another function `open_file()`, and prints the file through yet another function `print()`. But it seems like the file automatically gets closed at the end of `open_file()`, because `print()` shows no output.

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void open_file(fstream &file)
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter filename : ";
    cin >> name;
    file.open(name, ios::app);
    file.seekg(0);
}

void print(fstream &file)
{
    string temp;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        getline(file, temp);
        cout << temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    open_file(file);
    print(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open the file in *append* mode, which is a write-mode not a read-mode. So you open the file for writing only and not for reading from.

Also, don't use `while (!file.eof())`, it will not work as you expect. Instead do `while (getline(...))`.

Comment: Can you please eleborate a little?

Comment: @FaraazAhmad The `app` mode is opening the file in write-only mode, so you can't read from it.

Comment: So, should i use `file.open(name, ios::app | ios::in)` ?

Comment: @FaraazAhmad If you want to read then yes you need the `in` flag too.